# C# Minimum and maximum value

Tags: c#

My task is:
Data on the height of N students in a class are entered in turn. Determine the average, minimum and maximum height of students in the group.

I wrote such a solution, but the program incorrectly outputs the maximum and minimum values.

```
Console.Write("Number of students in the group = ");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

double result = 0;
double min = 0;
double max = 0;
for (double i = 0.0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.Write("The height of {0} student (in cm):  ", i + 1);
    double h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    result += h;
    if (max > h) max = h;
    if (h < max) min = h;
}
double average = 0;
average = result / n;
Console.WriteLine("Average value = " + average);
Console.WriteLine("Maximum value = " + max);
Console.WriteLine("Minimun value = " + min);
```

Output:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `if (max > h) max = h;` does not make sense: wouldn't you rather change `max` when `h` is greater than `max`, not the other way around? The next line is a pure typo, though: you meant to compare `h` to `min`, not to `max`, before assigning `min`.

Comment: I suggest you get acquainted with the visual studio debugger. That would have helped you detect the logical error. Sergey is right here.

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: "if max is bigger than h, set max to h" "if h is smaller than max, set min to h". Do these sound right to you?

Comment: Tip; if you want to find a maximum, start from an absolute minimum and work up. If you want to find a minimum start from an absolute maximum and work down. `double.MinValue` and `double.MaxValue` are constants programmed into c# that are helpful for such purposes. All the numeric types have these constants. 0 is in the middle of all possible range of signed values so not always a great choice

Answer (score 1):

if (h < max) min = h; is a bug,  since  at the start all values =0, and since height will never be less then 0, and will never be true and min will stay 0 forever.

if (max > h) max = h; does not make much sense too for  the same reason. Max is 0 at the start, so it will never  be true and max will be 0 forever.

Try this

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Number of students in the group = ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
    double result = 0;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("The height of {0} student (in cm):  ", i + 1);
        double h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(h.ToString());
        result += h;
        if (h > max) max = h;
        if ( min==0 || h < min) min = h;
    }
    double average = result / n;
    Console.WriteLine("Average height = " + average);
    Console.WriteLine("Maximum height = " + max);
    Console.WriteLine("Minimun heignt = " + min);
}
```

output

```
Number of students in the group = 5
The height of 1 student (in cm):  140
The height of 2 student (in cm):  150
The height of 3 student (in cm):  130
The height of 4 student (in cm):  170
The height of 5 student (in cm):  165
Average heignt = 151
Maximum heignt = 170
Minimun heignt = 130
```

Comment: Yes, but don't do their homework for them..